SQL query to retrieve only latest change to a record in a column
I have a table that stores employee information. This table is used by an external service to determine employee rates per hour. Each employee has a column attribute named EmployeeGroup. Everyone in a specific employee group gets the same rate. A change in EmployeeGroup means that the employee's rate should change as well. I need to extract only the latest change to the employee's group, which means we disregard any previous changes. If there are no changes, we also need to return the first instance of the group they belong to. Here is a crude example of the table I am working with (Not all columns present):



EmployeeId
FirstName
LastName
Position
startDate
EmployeeGroup
EmployeeSKey
ActionDesc




123
John
Smith
Intern
2016-01-01
Interns
1
Hired


123
John
Smith
Jnr Dev
2018-01-01
Juniors
2
Absorbed


123
John
Smith
Jnr Dev
2019-07-01
Juniors
4
Team Change


123
John
Smith
Mid-Level Dev
2021-01-01
Mid-Levels
5
Promotion


123
John
Smith
Senior Dev
2023-06-20
Seniors
9
Promotion


123
John
Smith
Senior Dev
2024-05-24
Seniors
11
Manager Change


456
Sally
Jones
Jnr Researcher
2022-01-07
Junior
6
Hired


789
Brody
James
N Wing Janitor
2018-01-01
Mid-Levels
3
Hired


789
Brody
James
S Wing Janitor
2022-01-01
Mid-Levels
7
Restructure


101
Paul
Gaib
Junior VP
2023-06-01
Jnr Executives
8
Nepotism


101
Paul
Gaib
Senior VP
2024-01-01
Snr Executives
10
Nepotism



As you may observe, John Smith (EmployeeId:123) underwent a number of changes. We disregard any previous changes and we only worry about his current group (Seniors) and when that happened on 2023-06-20 (5th row). Any subsequent rows that aren't a change in employee group are irrelevant.
I also need to return the 'default' StartDate if there isn't any change. e.g.) Brody James (EmployeeId 789) has remained a Mid-level even though there was a position change. Thus we only need the first date which was when he was hired (2018-01-01)
I created the following query, which I thought to retrieve the previous changes via LAG(). I was hoping to retrieve the last changed query and this would then give an indication of what's changed and what hasn't. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to extract only the latest and also the first of those that haven't changed their employee group.
WITH PreviousEmployeeChanges AS (
    SELECT
       EmployeeId,
       LAG(EmployeeGroup) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY EmployeeSKey) PrevSubgroup,
       LAG(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY EmployeeSKey) AS PrevStartDate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY EmployeeSKey desc) AS rn --Even thought to use this to somehow sort by latest change
    FROM
        Employees
)
--tried combining the CTE and original to perhaps give me my desired output
SELECT e.*, pec.PrevSubgroup, pec.PrevStartDate,
COALESCE(pec.PrevStartDate, e.startDate) AS LastChangedEmployeeGroup
FROM
    Employees e
JOIN
    PreviousEmployeeChanges pec ON e.employeeId = pec.employeeId 

I have not used a GROUP BY because there are about 30 other columns that also need to be returned. How can I correctly return the employees with only the latest change in employee group while accounting for those that never got changed? I am at my wits end on how to bring these two parts together.
Here is the desired result



EmployeeId
FirstName
LastName
Position
startDate
EmployeeGroup
EmployeeSKey
ActionDesc




123
John
Smith
Senior Dev
2023-06-20
Seniors
9
Promotion


456
Sally
Jones
Jnr Researcher
2022-01-07
Junior
6
Hired


789
Brody
James
N Wing Janitor
2018-01-01
Mid-Levels
3
Hired


101
Paul
Gaib
Senior VP
2024-01-01
Snr Executives
10
Nepotism



Here is the insert statement to replicate the above table if needed
INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName, Position, StartDate, EmployeeGroup, EmployeeSKey, ActionDesc)
VALUES
    (123, 'John', 'Smith', 'Intern', '2016-01-01', 'Interns', 1, 'Hired'),
    (123, 'John', 'Smith', 'Jnr Dev', '2018-01-01', 'Juniors', 2, 'Absorbed'),
    (123, 'John', 'Smith', 'Jnr Dev', '2019-07-01', 'Juniors', 4, 'Team Change'),
    (123, 'John', 'Smith', 'Mid-Level Dev', '2021-01-01', 'Mid-Levels', 5, 'Promotion'),
    (123, 'John', 'Smith', 'Senior Dev', '2023-06-20', 'Seniors', 9, 'Promotion'),
    (123, 'John', 'Smith', 'Senior Dev', '2024-05-24', 'Seniors', 11, 'Manager Change'),
    (456, 'Sally', 'Jones', 'Jnr Researcher', '2022-01-07', 'Junior', 6, 'Hired'),
    (789, 'Brody', 'James', 'N Wing Janitor', '2018-01-01', 'Mid-Levels', 3, 'Hired'),
    (789, 'Brody', 'James', 'S Wing Janitor', '2022-01-01', 'Mid-Levels', 7, 'Restructure'),
    (101, 'Paul', 'Gaib', 'Junior VP', '2023-06-01', 'Jnr Executives', 8, 'Nepotism'),
    (101, 'Paul', 'Gaib', 'Senior VP', '2024-01-01', 'Snr Executives', 10, 'Nepotism');



LAG did not exist in sql-server-2008 please run Select @@version and amend tags appropriately.

Aside... your upgrade plan for SQL Server 2008 should have concluded many years ago. You aren't really still using that are you?

Apologies, I added the tag incorrectly. Let me remove it to not  cause confusion.

What version do you use? What you try to do is already provided by temporal tables, in all supported versions, in a far better way that doesn't break FKs. Even if you're on an old version that doesn't support temporal tables, the best option is to emulate them, with a current table and a separate History table. Any operations on the current table should update the history table using eg triggers.

If you can't use temporal tables, or if you want to search the History table, you can use FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE to retrieve the first/last value in a partition by a specific order, eg LAST_VALUE(Positiong) OVER(Partition by EmployeeID ORDER by StartDate desc) as Position, Max(StartDate),... You'll have to use DISTINCT to eliminate the resulting duplicate rows. In this example you can use ActionDesc to eliminate unwanted rows.

I would add a left outer join sub select and in this select group on User Id, then do a count of EmployeeSKey and also max of EmployeeSKey
That would give you the count of changes and latest (max).

@PanagiotisKanavos I use SQL Server 2022, and I should probably do some more reading on temporal tables. Thanks for that! I also however did not want to use ActionDesc to eliminate unwanted rows as the text is dynamic and is susceptible to change.

Calculate the minimum StartDate per user/group combinations, then join that to the source table. Then use row_number() partitioned only by UserId but ordered by the calculated minimum date descending so that the most recent change is identified together with the earliest date of that change:
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
           e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Position, c.min_dt, e.StartDate, e.EmployeeGroup, e.EmployeeSKey, e.ActionDesc
        ,  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmployeeId ORDER BY min_dt DESC, e.StartDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM employees e
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT EmployeeId, EmployeeGroup
            , min(StartDate) min_dt
        FROM employees
        GROUP BY EmployeeId, EmployeeGroup
        ) c ON e.EmployeeId = c.EmployeeId and e.EmployeeGroup = c.EmployeeGroup 
    ) d
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY EmployeeId




EmployeeId
FirstName
LastName
Position
min_dt.......
StartDate...
EmployeeGroup
EmployeeSKey
ActionDesc
rn




101
Paul
Gaib
Senior VP
2024-01-01
2024-01-01
Snr Executives
10
Nepotism
1


123
John
Smith
Senior Dev
2023-06-20
2024-05-24
Seniors
11
Manager Change
1


456
Sally
Jones
Jnr Researcher
2022-01-07
2022-01-07
Junior
6
Hired
1


789
Brody
James
S Wing Janitor
2018-01-01
2022-01-01
Mid-Levels
7
Restructure
1



See the (modified for new sample data) dbfiddle

Based on original sample data:
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
           e.UserId, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Position, c.min_dt, e.StartDate, e.EmployeeGroup, e.EmployeeSKey, e.ActionDescription
        ,  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY e.UserId ORDER BY min_dt DESC, e.StartDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM employees e
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT UserId, EmployeeGroup
            , min(StartDate) min_dt
        FROM employees
        GROUP BY UserId, EmployeeGroup
        ) c ON e.UserId = c.UserId and e.EmployeeGroup = c.EmployeeGroup 
    ) d
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY UserId

Note these results differ to your given expected result (but I think there ares some errors in in the expected result e.g. "N Wing Janitor")



UserId
FirstName
LastName
Position
min_dt.......
StartDate...
EmployeeGroup
EmployeeSKey
ActionDescription
rn




101
Paul
Gaib
Senior VP
2024-01-01
2024-01-01
Snr Executives
11
Nepotism
1


123
John
Smith
Senior Dev
2023-06-20
2024-01-24
Seniors
6
Manager change
1


456
Sally
Jones
Junior Researcher
2022-01-07
2022-01-07
Juniors
7
Hired
1


789
Brody
James
Janitor
2018-01-02
2022-01-09
Intermediates
9
Manager change
1



see this dbfiddle

There are differences in the question between the top table and the INSERT INTO data - OP needs to address that, and then of course the expected result needs to be reviewed as well.

@DávidLaczkó you are indeed right. I made modifications on the top table for clarity before posting, but used different table which I converted to the INSERT INTO statement. I'll add the correct INSERT INTO code to the post. Apologies, especially to Adrian his response which looks different to the expected output. But it is a massively helpful response for sure.

I have updated my answer for the new sample data (and new field names) and aside from the row order the new result above matches the new expected result I believe.

btw: I have added ..... in result headings only so that dates don't wrap

@ByteDem Hi. As you appear to be new to the site please read this What should I do when someone answers my question?
